# Can't install Boot Repair on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

After the installation I have booted to my USB again and performed the following usual steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

I get no error messages following the first 3 steps. However on the last I get the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair
```

There are a lot of questions like this one asked here. However the solutions always seems to be the 4 steps I already use. Please help

Edit:
Here is the full output performing the 4 steps the 2nd time:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
 Simple tool to repair frequent boot problems.

Website: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpou5r8p95/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpou5r8p95/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 60D8DA0B from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpou5r8p95/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 60D8DA0B: public key "Launchpad PPA for YannUbuntu" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) trusty InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) vivid InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) trusty/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) trusty/restricted Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) vivid/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) vivid/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) vivid/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805) vivid/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_yannubuntu_boot-repair_ubuntu_dists_saucy_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_yannubuntu_boot-repair_ubuntu_dists_saucy_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Comment: @Kulfy The other question is entirely and utterly unrelated. Neither the question nor its answers are relevant in any way.

Comment: The APT cache wasn't updates because of the duplicacy. The warning message was modified a bit in the later releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in the repository there is no packages for saucy release. Maybe you could try installing the one for the trusty release (i.e. omitting the second command

```
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
```

)