# Accidentally uninstalled gnome-software in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-center

I accidentally removed gnome-software while trying to fix a problem where I would get random desktop freezes (I stupidly followed the advice on a random forum). This is the relevant portion of the iterm.log:

````
(Reading database ... 243899 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-software (3.20.1+git20160617.1.0440874.ubuntu-xenial-    0ubuntu1~16.04.1) ...
Removing gnome-software (3.20.1+git20160617.1.0440874.ubuntu-xenial-0ubuntu1~16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...```
````

I thought I should be able to just reinstall what was uninstalled but I can't seem to do that (at least not through `apt-get`).

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ubuntu-software is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ubuntu-software' has no installation candidate
```

and a similar message for gnome-software

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-software
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-software is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-software' has no installation candidate
```

I thought maybe it was due to my sources in the software & updates but I've enabled all of the sources that I thought could possibly have the packages. I have enabled the following sources:

[image: screenshot of sources]

Output of `apt-get update`:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:11 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/gnome-software/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:13 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:16 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Fetched 190 kB in 1s (160 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:3
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:3
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:4
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:5
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:3
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:3
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:4
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-software-xenial.list:5
```

Output of `apt-cache policy gnome-software`:

```
gnome-software:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: (none)
    Version table:
     3.20.1+git20160617.1.0440874.ubuntu-xenial-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Screenshot of Software & Updates app:

[image: updates screen]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) and [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI for anyone who may run into this:

1. removed everything in `/var/lib/apt/lists`
2. followed instructions outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories/124024#124024).
3. ran `apt-get update && apt-get install gnome-software`