# Cannot update texstudio to 2.11.2-7.1

Tags: latex

```
The following packages will be upgraded:            texstudio
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
45 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 15.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 50.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jsundermeyer/xUbuntu_14.04  texstudio 2.11.2-7.1 [15.2 MB]
Fetched 15.2 MB in 1min 37s (156 kB/s)                                         
(Reading database ... 315110 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texstudio_2.11.2-7.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking texstudio (2.11.2-7.1) over (2.10.8+debian-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.11.2-7.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texstudio/template_Letter.tex', which is also in package texstudio-doc 2.10.8+debian-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.11.2-7.1_amd64.deb
W: Target Sources (non-free/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Sources (non-free/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I tried to update texstudio on my ubuntu, it gave this error, can anyone kindly help me how to fix the error. Many thanks

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-automatically-fix-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times.

Comment: @edwinksl That should take care of the warnings, but what about the errors: `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.11.2-7.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texstudio/template_Letter.tex', which is also in package texstudio-doc 2.10.8+debian-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)`

Comment: @NickWeinberg Nice catch, I missed that. Let OP fix the warnings first and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the synaptic package manager, I did a complete removal of texstudio and re-installed the software, it seems the software was updated to 2.11.2. Although I still have the error when I do `sudo apt-get update`, it gives the following error

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/blahota/texstudio/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jsundermeyer/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.gpg: Signature by key BCFF88CB8BD5D98263D861BA21BD0C6DEA279317 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/blahota/texstudio/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My guess is that the package was removed from the server. But anyway, the updated version works fine for now, thanks to anyone who intended to help!

Comment: Yeah, that 404 error means the PPA doesn't have an installation candidate for `texstudio` for Ubuntu 16.04.