# Error messages when updating ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I am a total newbie to Ubuntu, and any Linux distro for the matter. So far I have been able to watch videos and research on google how to install all the programs I need but when I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following messages.

```
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https// could not be found.
W: The repository 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xenlism-wildfire/repo deb/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https//://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
```

I have tried `apt-get clean` and read [this link here](https://askubuntu.com/q/760896/51957) but that didn't help.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try `apt-get -f -y install`. Maybe this will fix it.

Comment: Hi zx485, Thank you for your input. I tried the command but unfortunately no luck there. This is what it stated below root@MacroEconomics:~# apt-get -f -y install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded. Then after I did apt-get update and received the same message as my original post.

Comment: @Newguy2122, you have some duplicate sources and one is with HTTPS which is not supported, Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `grep -rn "deb" /etc/apt/sources.list*`