# Intel Graphics Updater - "Updating package cache... Failed" (Ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: intel-graphics, 16.10, xps

I'm having trouble updating Intel drivers with the Intel Graphics Update Tool v2.0.3.

[image: When the error occurs]

And this is the error window:

[image: Error]

I'm using an XPS 13 FHD with an i5-6200U and Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2), running Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository for the `Intel Graphics Installer for Linux` requires a gpg public key. From https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.3, we see that we need to add this gpg public key. Enter the following commands in `terminal`...

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-GROUP-KEY-ilg

sudo apt-key add RPM-GPG-GROUP-KEY-ilg
```

To solve the lists defined multiple times, again, in `terminal`...

```
ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list*
```

You'll probably see something like this:

```
arc-theme.list
arc-theme.list:1
arc-theme.list:2
arc-theme.list:3
```

We want to delete all but the first one:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:2
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:3
```