# Software updates fail Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS on my PC, each time Software Updater alter pops up I click on `Update Now` and I enter my credentials to proceed.

But each time it fails and shows an error message that says that there is some issue with my Internet connection, But my Internet connection works fine.

[image]

When I use `sudo apt update` following messages come.

```
Fetched 6,200 kB in 7s (776 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
191 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1515625755
W: http://packages.elastic.co/kibana/4.5/debian/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 46095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1515625755
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you open a terminal window and type in `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`?  If those run, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1003451/edit) your question and copy and paste the output to your question.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for the comment I have edited the post

Comment: I see a couple problems.  First look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times/762815 for the `W:` lines that are multiples.  The other part is look at https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ for your public key failure on Mongodb 3.4

Comment: what is there in cat /etc/apt/sources.list ? add it to your question.