# How do I install LAMMPS?

Tags: package-management, updates, ppa

I am trying to install lammps software but I see this error when I update:

```
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gladky-anton/lammps/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ci-ubuntu-stable-artful.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ci-ubuntu-stable-artful.list:3
```

I typed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gladky-anton/lammps
sudo apt-get update
```

But get this error:

```
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gladky-anton/lammps/ubuntu artful Release      
404  Not Found
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default 

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gladky-anton/lammps/ubuntu artful 
Release' does not have a Release file.

W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ci-ubuntu-stable-artful.list:2 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ci-ubuntu-stable-artful.list:3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)