# How to Fix W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I am pretty much a noob at Linux and have only been using it for like 3 weeks. When in terminal for sudo apt-get update I get the below errors.

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_ZA) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_ZA) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
```

Can anyone help me in fixing these?
Really appreciate it.
Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the duplicate post, I did not see a solution to this until about 2 hours after posting. If anyone sees this and is needing a solution, I found a working one here. [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)
Thanks to David Foerster.