# Are warning messages about duplicate packages blocking?

Tags: apt, package-management

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times), we learn how to clean up the duplicate message warnings when running apt-get.

What I am wondering is are these duplicate source messages, blocking, which prevent updates or informational -- do they need to be cleaned up, or are just visual spam?

I can't tell if I have no updates, or if because of the duplicates its not checking further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the lines that begin with `W` are warnings, those with an initial `E` indicate errors, and `N` indicates a Note. For example,

```
W: http://repo.sinew.in/dists/stable/InRelease: Signature by key B6DA722E2E65721AF54B93966F7565879798C2FC uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
^
```

For these two, there's nothing to be done at your end for the "`weak digest algorithm`" - it causes no active harm. However, the "`404`" error indicates a failure that should be fixed, as it describes a lack of connection/misconfiguration.

In general, in the Linux/Unix world, silence implies success. If the program issues a message, you should least consider it, and try to figure out what it means.

Comment: I was asking specific to situation in the linked thread. Duplicate entries. I cant tell if there is simply nothing to update, or if because of the duplicate sources it was failing to check. None of my links are reporting 404. I will update the question. Sorry about the delay in responding.

Comment: @RowanHawkins Warnings vs. Errors typically remains the same regardless of the specific case.  In that thread you reference there's both warnings *and* errors.  Warnings are warnings, Errors are Errors, and that doesn't change on context of what the messages themselves are.  Most, if not all, 'warnings' are non-blocking to my knowledge.

Comment: @ThomasWard you say _most_ warnings are not blocking. That would imply that _some_ are blocking.  Which variety, blocking or non-blocking are warnings related to duplicate source messages.

Comment: @Rowan All the warnings in the context of your post fit the "non blocking" category, and I believe that all warnings are non-blocking but was being cautious with wording.  (Therefore: Most, if not all, 'warnings' are non-blocking to my knowledge.)