# Package Manager update error

Tags: software-center

Kindly help me with this error. All the applications on the software centre are not loading and package manger has error too.

[Error while trying to update from package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m57Oo.png)

Comment: The problems, and how to fix them, seem clearly and plainly stated in the error message. Are you asking how to edit a text file? (if so, use the Search feature to look it up)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err) and to fix the warning messages [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Answer (score -2):

I guess u have wrote the entry of repositories multiple time in source.list

Open etc/apt/sources.list using

```
nano etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now look at the entries and check if it matches with official repository for your linux distro and look for redundancy
 Repair it and then Press `Ctrl` + `X` for exiting.

Press `Y` for saving the buffer and then press `Enter` and than type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Consider editing your answer. It does not look as complete working instruction. Fix typos.