# Errors in apt-update in Ubuntu Mate (Raspberry pi)

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, raspberrypi

When I try to to use `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update` at the very end I get all these errors and it exits:

```
Ign:48 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                                                             
Fetched 600 kB in 14s (40.8 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-armhf/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-armhf.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-armhf/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-armhf.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:7
battledash@battledash-desktop:~$
```

Edit: This is Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**W** stands for ***Warning*** and **E** for ***Error***.

- For **Warnings** like `Target Packages is configured multiple times...`:

  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/762815/816190) by David Foerster will help to remove duplicate entries.
- For **Errors**:

  1. The file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` had useless lines which do not provide any sort of updates. Commenting out that helped.
  2. The error `....i386` was due to the addition of wrong, i.e. 32 bit architecture. Remove that using

     ```
     sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
     ```

Try updating again.

Comment: i386 is x86 32bit architecture, armv6 & armv7 are also 32bit with armv8 being 64bit arm architecture.   (armhf = arm hard float of v7 (& up) 32bit).

Comment: @guiverc but in my opinion adding that architecture was useless. Also files armhf weren't located at that URL.