# Kalarm install problem and "is configured multiple times" error

Tags: package-management

I installed `kalarm` and got some errors, quoted below, and `kalarm` said it was unable to create the first alarm.  Now "New" alarm is grayed out as well as some other options.  Tried resetting to defaults and also removing and reinstalling but no change.

Errors installing `kalarm`:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
```

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)