# Package r-base-core is not configured yet in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, r

I used `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but it shows like below.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-class:
 r-cran-class depends on r-base-core (>= 3.5.0-1); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-class depends on r-api-3.5; however:
  Package r-api-3.5 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-3.5 is not configured yet
```

How do I fix it?

Output of `apt depends r-cran-class`:

```
r-cran-class
  Depends: r-base-core
  Depends: r-cran-mass
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
```

Output of `apt-cache policy r-cran-class`:

```
r-cran-class:
  Installed: 7.3-15-1cran1ppabionic0
  Candidate: 7.3-15-1cran1ppabionic0
  Version table:
 *** 7.3-15-1cran1ppabionic0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/c2d4u3.5/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.3-15-1bionic0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter3.5/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     7.3-14-2xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     7.3-14-2cranArtful0~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     7.3-14-2build1 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     7.3-14-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
```

Output of `apt-cache policy r-api-3.5`:

```
r-api-3.5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Output of `sudo dpkg --configure r-base-core`:

```
Setting up r-base-core (3.6.1-1bionic) ...
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
 installed r-base-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r-base-core
```

Output of `sudo apt install --reinstall r-base-core`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for r-base-core:amd64
```

Output of `apt-cache policy r-base-core`:

```
r-base-core:
  Installed: 3.6.1-1bionic
  Candidate: 3.6.1-1bionic
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.1-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.6.0-2bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.6.0-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.3.20190412-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.5.3-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.2-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.1-2bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.1-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.0-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.4.4-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     3.4.3-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.2-2xenial2 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.2-1xenial1 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.1-2xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.1-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.0-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.3-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.2-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.1-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.0-2xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.0-1xenial0 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.2.5-1xenial 500
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:91 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
```

After removing `xenial` and `cloud.r-project.org` from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and used `wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r-base/r-base-core_3.4.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` then the `sources.list` file looks like..

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb [arch=i386,amd64] https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
# deb-src [arch=i386,amd64] https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/
# deb-src http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/
```

But when i run `sudo dpkg -i r-base-core_3.4.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` then it showed:

```
mp@mp:~$ sudo dpkg -i r-base-core_3.4.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for mp: 
dpkg: warning: downgrading r-base-core from 3.5.3.20190412-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 to 3.4.4-1ubuntu1
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-sil-abyssinica' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libatk-adaptor:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libvorbisfile3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libquadmath0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxkbfile1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-sound-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-apt-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgs9-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnpth0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libqt5qml5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgtk2.0-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkf5config-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-pip-whl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkf5archive5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'imagemagick-6-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-goa-1.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libglib-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libslf4j-java' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapt-pkg5.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xcursor-themes' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libglvnd0:amd64' missing; 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwacom-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-keybinder-3.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcaca-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gtk-update-icon-cache' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsnapd-glib1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sensible-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpixman-1-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-gi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjline2-java' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-mahjongg' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'acpid' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'grilo-plugins-0.3-base:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xtrans-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmp3lame0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-mlym' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libservlet3.1-java' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'geoclue-2.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libblas3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-protobuf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-sil-padauk' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'language-pack-en' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxcb-dri3-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkf5sonnetcore5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dpkg-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-six' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'x11proto-xext-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libqt5quicktemplates2-5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sonnet-plugins' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
 assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libqtdbus4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkeybinder-3.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxcb-xkb1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsimple-http-java' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libavahi-core7:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 11859 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack r-base-core_3.4.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-base-core (3.4.4-1ubuntu1) over (3.5.3.20190412-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1) ...
Setting up r-base-core (3.4.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/R/Makeconf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/R/Renviron.site ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/R/repositories ...
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--install):
 installed r-base-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r-base-core
```

Now suddenly ubuntu software `Software Updater` showed an error message like:

```
The package system is broken

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

r-cran-foreign: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
                Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.5.1-1bionic) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is installed
                Depends: r-api-3.5 but it is a virtual package
r-cran-kernsmooth: Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.5.0-1bionic) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is installed
                   Depends: r-api-3.5 but it is a virtual package
r-cran-nnet: Depends: r-api-3.5 but it is a virtual package
r-cran-spatial: Depends: r-api-3.5 but it is a virtual package
```

I think i need to remove `3.4.4-1ubuntu1`, `2.27-3ubuntu1` and install `sudo dpkg -i r-base-core_3.5.1-1bionic_amd64.deb`
**Am i right?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96207/discussion-on-question-by-mamun-pramanik-package-r-base-core-is-not-configured-y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's fix the issues one by one.

1. #### Remove r-base-core:

   Run

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove r-base-core
   ```
2. #### `W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times`

   The easiest way to solve this issue is following [David's Script](https://askubuntu.com/a/762815/816190). But if you don't want to follow that script and since you have issue in single line, you can simply run,

   ```
   sudo sed -i '4d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list
   ```
3. #### Remove PPAs of  some other release.

   Since you are using Bionic Beaver (18.04), Xenial Xerus's (16.04) PPA information won't help in anyway and might create dependency problems in future. I would suggest removing or commenting them. Run

   ```
   grep "xenial" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
   ```

   It would generate output which would help you to determine those files. Edit them using sudo privileges and some editor such as nano and put a `#` in front of them. To open them run

   ```
   sudo nano filename
   ```

   Save them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>. If those files contain a single line only which is of xenial, you may delete that.
4. #### `dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'x' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed`

   Copy whole error message in some text file, say 1.txt and run

   ```
   for package in $(cat 1.txt | grep "warning: files list file" | sed "s/.*\`//; s/'.*//"); do echo "$package"; done >> 2.txt
   ```

   <sup>**Credits:** [zaTricky's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/607236) on [dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'x' missing](https://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing)</sup>

   Copy all packages name and run

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall packages_name
   ```

   You can reinstall multiple packages by pasting multiple packages' name in one command.
5. #### Configure (if some left):

   Run:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
6. #### Install r-base:

   Run

   ```
   sudo apt install r-base
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A mix between bionic xenial artful and ppa packages.

Remove under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` any file with xenial or artful in name.

Control in `/etc/apt/sources.list` That every row leads to a bionic source.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:marutter/rrutter3.5
```

removes that ppa.

You have another on `cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35` for that packages. I'am not sure if this works. `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get clean`

```
sudo apt -f install --reinstall r-cran-class=7.3-15-1bionic0
```

If is not working `wget -c https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran35/r-cran-class_7.3-15-1bionic0_amd64.deb` for 64-bit or `wget -c https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran35/r-cran-class_7.3-15-1bionic0_i386.deb` for 32-bit system.  Install it directly with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/your deb` `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Not working after using your solution.