# Error when trying to get ppa:mc3man/trusty-media

Tags: apt, ppa, ffmpeg

I am trying to install specific version of FFMPEG (4.1.4), but, when I try to execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
```

I get following error message:

```
Hit:1 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:5 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease             
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (stable/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons (stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (stable/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target DEP-11-icons (stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
```

Same thing happens once I try and execute `sudo apt-get update`. I honestly dont have much experience with Linux, I saw that people tried edditing /etc/apt/sources.list but I am really not sure which line should I comment out or even if that is the right approach. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) **Please note that if using this ppa I would *not* try upgrading to 14.10/15.04, ect. Do a fresh install instead. The intent here is just for users wishing to stay on 14.04** and [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/)

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/  is intended for Ubuntu (trusty) 14.04 LTS.  You are running bionic/18.04 and not trusty/14.04.  Ubuntu 14.04 is EOL and off-topic here