# libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.22) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, lubuntu, dpkg, dependencies

After an update on Ubuntu 18.04 I have some problems, for example when trying to update, remove or install some package I get:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.22) but it is not going to be installed
 libfreetype6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libfuse2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 liblzma5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 libpcre3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libpng16-16:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libselinux1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
 libudev1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try
```

'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

How to fix that?

I tried to do several things:

1. apt --fix-broken install
2. sudo apt-get install -f
3. sudo dpkg --configure -a

and others. But nothing helped. Now I can only use the system, nothing else.

For `apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jelmer/daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jelmer/daily/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                                                                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                                                                                                                                  
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                          
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]                                                                                                           
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]                                                                                                
Hit:10 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                                                                        
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/source/Sources' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jelmer/daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
```

Edit:

```
apt-get update

Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jelmer/daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]  
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jelmer/daily/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                 
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [516 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]       
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [373 kB]                           
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [173 kB]                                              
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [585 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [26,4 kB]                     
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [37,8 kB]                            
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [7 648 B]                    
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted Translation-en [3 064 B]                                      
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [607 kB]                                          
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [739 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [591 kB]                      
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [202 kB]                       
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [285 kB]                           
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42,1 kB]                           
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [116 kB]                                  
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4 904 B]                                
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse Translation-en [2 396 B]        
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [70,9 kB]               
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [140 kB]  
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [979 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1 006 kB]                                                                                                                 
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [254 kB]                                                                                                            
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [202 kB]                                                                                                               
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [452 kB]                                                                                                               
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 468 B]                                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jelmer/daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.22) but it is not installed
 libfreetype6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libfuse2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not installed
 liblzma5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installed
 libpcre3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libpng16-16:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libselinux1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not installed
 libudev1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).




sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfuse2:i386 libmaxminddb0 libpng16-16:i386 libsmi2ldbl libwireshark-data libwireshark11 libwiretap8 libwscodecs2 libwsutil9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2 551 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10,8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 453920 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfuse2:i386 libmaxminddb0 libpng16-16:i386 libsmi2ldbl libwireshark-data libwireshark11 libwiretap8 libwscodecs2 libwsutil9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2 551 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10,8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 453920 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

sudo dpkg --configure -a

Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Comment: Your sources are a mess of duplicates, I would suggest cleaning them up (and check before adding a source again to see if it's already present).  What is your architecture?  libc6 2.23 is default for bionic (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libc6) which meets requirement so are you likely need to add x86/i386 sources - though I'd look at why you're adding it first (details not provided as it looks you're running amd64/x86_64) and your sources are already a mess. Is there a reason for the 2nd architecture?

Comment: No this no reason for second architecture. My architecture is: x86_64

Comment: As your architecture is x86_64 - look further up the pasted listing and you may see why you've added 32bit archives & packages; if not there maybe `apt-cache rdepends libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 --installed` to for clues as to why it was installed previously?

Comment: The reason for the 32-bit packages is probably Wine. There's no reason why it should cause those problems, though... Please provide the outputs of the commands you say you tried.

Comment: Ok, I added some more info and outputs of the commands.

Comment: Right, the `Resource temporarily unavailable` parts are what you should be looking into...

Comment: This is not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) and [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/760896/)

Comment: @N0rbert after performing simmilar steps I get another error: E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jelmer/daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: Now I can't even upgrade or install any package.