# Trying to update ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, phpmyadmin

Hi everyone I`m trying to update my ubuntu version and i have encountered an issue. When trying to update my installed packages I get 403 for some of them.

How can I fix this issue so that I can update my ubuntu version

```
Hit:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/nautilus-extensions/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit:6 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                         
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable InRelease                       
Hit:11 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Hit:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:14 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial InRelease                   
Hit:15 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease                         
Hit:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease             
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Err:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial Release         
  403  Forbidden
Err:20 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Err:22 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu cosmic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu cosmic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times) and [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/13065/)

Comment: @karel didnt work for me