# Ubuntu: Target Packages is configured multiple times

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

**P/S:** Before you mark or vote this question as duplicate, I wanted to post my answer here ([How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)), but the question has been protected, which made me to resort to asking a new question and answering it.

I just installed a new copy of Linux OS (Ubuntu 18.04) on my local machine, and I am currently installing new applications.

I have successfully installed some applications, however after installing **Opera Browser**, I seem to run into an error.

Each time I run the command

```
sudo apt update
```

in my terminal, I get the error

```
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
```

displayed multiple times.

I have tried to make some research on how to solve this, but there seems to be no solution yet. I need some assistance.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was caused as a result of unknowingly adding **Opera Stable apt-repository** to the **sources list**.

**Here's how I fixed it**

**Solution 1**

Open your terminal or command line, and type the following

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will open your sources list in the nano editor

Simply scroll down the list and comment out the line that is causing the issue.

For me it was the opera stable apt-repository line

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
```

All I had to do was to comment it out, like this

```
# deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
```

Then exit the file, by pressing

```
Ctrl + X
```

And then Press **Y** on your keyboard to save the changes.

**Solution 2**

1. Open the **Software and Updates** application
2. Click on the **Other Software** tab
3. Scroll down and click on **Opera Browser (final releases) stable**
4. Click the **Remove** button at the bottom
5. After the removal, click the **Refresh** button to update your cache

[image: Screenshot of the solution]

That's all.

**I hope this helps.**

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [the latest package to solve the problem](https://github.com/davidfoerster/aptsources-cleanup/releases/download/v0.1.7.5.1/aptsources-cleanup.pyz) .

1. Install the prerequisites:

   ```
    sudo apt install python3-apt
   ```
2. From the download location of the PYZ bundle run:

   ```
    sudo python3 -OEs aptsources-cleanup.pyz
   ```
3. Follow the instructions appearing on the screen.

**REFERENCE** = https://askubuntu.com/a/762815/1122646

Comment: Doesn't work: $ sudo python3 -OEs aptsources-cleanup.pyz
No duplicate entries were found.