# Errors during updating ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

```
sudo apt update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Release [574 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Release [574 B]                                                           
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                            
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                                                                            
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                                                                           
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                             
Hit:7 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                    
Ign:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                     
Hit:12 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Err:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic Release                                                                                                                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.56.204 80]
Get:14 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic InRelease [3,169 B]                                                                                                                       
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stefansundin/truecrypt/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                         
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                                                                                                      
Hit:17 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease                                                                                                                             
Hit:18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                                            
Hit:19 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                                                         
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu focal Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:14 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23
rebeen@rebeen-Precision-5520:~$
```

This is the sources.list

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ quantal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ saucy universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.lchost.net/debian/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main
```

This is the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
rebeen@rebeen-Precision-5520:~$ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
rebeen@rebeen-Precision-5520:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls

```
armagetronad-dev-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list       graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list       mongodb-org-3.6.list.distUpgrade                vscode.list
armagetronad-dev-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save  graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save  mongodb-org-3.6.list.save                       vscode.list.distUpgrade
brave-browser.list.save                      inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list        opera-stable.list                               vscode.list.save
brave-browser-release-bionic.list            inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list.save   opera-stable.list.save                          webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list
brave-browser-release-bionic.list.save       mendeleydesktop.list                          stefansundin-ubuntu-truecrypt-bionic.list       webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.distUpgrade
cuda-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48.list         mendeleydesktop.list.distUpgrade              stefansundin-ubuntu-truecrypt-bionic.list.save  webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save
cuda-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48.list.save    mendeleydesktop.list.save                     teamviewer.list                                 webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-focal.list
google-chrome.list                           midori-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list                 teamviewer.list.save                            webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-focal.list.save
google-chrome.list.distUpgrade               midori-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save            ubuntu-mate-dev-ubuntu-welcome-focal.list
google-chrome.list.save                      mongodb-org-3.2.list                          ubuntu-mate-dev-ubuntu-welcome-focal.list.save
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) and [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/13065)

Comment: above output is just saying your have duplicate lines in the config file(s) so remove them ... `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list`   ... above says for example `configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:23`   so eyeball those two lines and confirm this is so then if so delete line 23 ... rinse and repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the following sources. These are all trivial errors the you could easily diagnose for yourself - simply follow the URLs in any web browser, and check the 'dists' directory for your current release of Ubuntu:

```
http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic Release
http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu focal Release
```

Your pubkey error (`Err:14 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic InRelease`) is answered at [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

All those "W: Target Packages *X* is configured multiple times in *Y* and *Z*" is answered at [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Comment: Thank you very much, I added the sources.list of my computer in which I cannot find the above sources

Comment: Look in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: Thank you, sorry but it is empty (sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/)

Comment: That is because /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ is a *directory*, not a file. You must look at each file within that directory.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I did not know, but I cannot find the sources that should be removed as you I shown the directory above.

Comment: Look again.... I see all three of them in the sources you are showing.