# fatal error in (chrome) png image file: Write error

Tags: google-chrome, dependencies, png

[i got png file error and ran this command to resolve it-  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng*-dev`]

**output of command**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpng-dev' for glob 'libpng*-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng2-dev' for glob 'libpng*-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng16-dev' for glob 'libpng*-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' for glob 'libpng*-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng12-0-dev' for glob 'libpng*-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpnglite-dev' for glob 'libpng*-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng++-dev' for glob 'libpng*-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng3-dev' for glob 'libpng*-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng12-0-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng3-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng16-dev : Depends: libpng16-devtools (= 1.6.20-2) but it is not going to be installed
                Conflicts: libpng12-0-dev
                Conflicts: libpng12-dev but 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: libpng3-dev
                Recommends: libpng16-tools but it is not going to be installed
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
**E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages**
```

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  I seem to see two releases of packages listed in your messages.

Comment: @guiverc 16.04 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) and [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/760896/)