# Can't upgrade OS Install (MATE); How to solve, please?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I have seen similar issues but am not being able to quite solve the issue...

Probably easy I guess...

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt_BR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-pt) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
```

Appreciate a lot!

Comment: @Risen do you have any `E:` on running `sudo apt update`? What is your Ubuntu MATE version?

Comment: Hi Pilot6, appreciate a lot! But unfortunately no: "udo python3 -OEs aptsources-cleanup.pyz
python3: can't open file 'aptsources-cleanup.pyz': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
"

Comment: No @N0rbert, it does not bring me any E:s Appreciate!

Comment: @Risen It seems you didn't download [David's script](https://askubuntu.com/a/762815/816190) or tried to execute from different folder. As a result, you got `python3: can't open file 'aptsources-cleanup.pyz': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to remove *vivaldi.list* with:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list
```

and then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I guesss it helped, cause I removed it, then graphically as there was still something. But only after I changed the mirror (launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) to a new one it worked! Appreciate a lot!