# Read only file system after update failure

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, sudo

I tried to install some updates on my Ubuntu 20.04. If failed with the below error:

*There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks*.

Then I tried to continue with a partial update. But my password have been changed or corrupted. I can't run anything with *sudo* either because this password issue. Most of the settings cannot be changed in the settings app.
File system seems to be read only. No external drives are mountable.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: A *file-system* flips to RO when corruption is detected (power glitch, failing drive or other error; I'd check SMART anyway), error messages are found in the logs (`dmesg` is where I'd look first), but if that occurred during the updates, `apt` having errors would be expected. I would look at why, then boot *live* media & validate the health of your hardware (SMART) & then `fsck` (file-system check) your file-systems and everything will likely be okay then... but explore first as it could be a warning of problems coming....

Answer (score 0):

There was a file corruption on root partition. Had to run fsck manually upon reboot.

Also there were duplicates on the apt config. Had to remove them manually too.
[How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times#)