# why do i have three apt sources.list files?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, software-sources

I recently updated to 20.10 and am having numerous problems, but the first being, I cant update apt. every time i try i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
```

So i checked my /etc/apt/sources.list file and after the upgrade i now have three of them, every one completely different from the next. I don't know which one is correct and if i should remove them or combine them. my sources.list file looks like...

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main restricted # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates restricted multiverse main universe # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security restricted multiverse main universe # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports universe multiverse main restricted
```

my sources.list #2 looks like...

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)]/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-proposed multiverse main restricted universe
```

My sources.list file #3

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)]/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-proposed multiverse main restricted universe
```

i have no idea how to fix this, what i should comment out, what should be there and what should not. I'm thinking i need to combine and remove, but which ones? how do i fix this so i can properly update and upgrade my repo's?

Comment: Note that #2 and #3 are identical

Comment: What do you mean by "three `sources.list`s"? You can't have multiple files with the same name.

Comment: so if i remove one that should alleviate the files being sourced multiple times, correct?

Comment: i have sources.list, sources.list~ and sources.list~~

Comment: Related: [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/760896/301745)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, based on [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310719/why-do-i-have-three-apt-sources-list-files#comment2230462_1310719), the second two have tildes appended to their filenames, which means they're backups and not actually in use.

The error message says `/etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2`. The colons here are a conventional way of writing **line numbers**. So the problem seems to be on lines 1 and 2 in `sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main restricted # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
```

Here, the words after `groovy` are a list of repositories. The problem seems to be that the `main` and `restricted` repositories are listed twice. So simply comment out line 2, and that should fix the problem.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main universe restricted multiverse
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main restricted # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
...
```

I don't know how this happened.

Comment: After doing so, it will save the file as a different sources.list file, correct? So i need to remove the original sources.list file?

Comment: that worked great, thank you wjandrea! I was able to update, however i belive its still trying to source from sources.list~ and sources.list~~ because after updating i'm getting

Comment: @Toxic I'm not sure what you mean about removing the original. If you're really not sure what you're doing, run `gedit admin:///etc/apt/sources.list`, edit it, and save it like you normally would.

Comment: ok, i used emacs to edit it and save. thats why i asked, because emacs usually replicates the file with the changes saved as another sources.list file.

Comment: This is the warning i'm getting after updating.                                                                          Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/focal-infra-updates/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4067E40313CB4B13
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @Toxic That seems to be a very similar issue since it mentions "focal" instead of "groovy', but I'm not familiar with ESM so I'm not sure what's going on there. Please ask a new question, referencing this one.

Comment: im new to stackExchange, how do i properly reference this question so that it creates a link? sorry for so many questions.

Comment: @Toxic No worries! There's a little "Share" button under the question you can click to get a link.