# GPG error on updates?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, gnupg

I was having a problem updating apt due to the sources.list files being sourced and commented incorrectly (refer to [why do i have three apt sources.list files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1310719/1175084)). We were able to resolve the problem and i was able to update, partially. I'm now getting a warning that says,

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4067E40313CB4B13
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4067E40313CB4B13
W: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/focal-infra-security/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4067E40313CB4B13
W: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/focal-infra-updates/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4067E40313CB4B13
```

How do i resolve this? I tried importing the keys using

```
 wget https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu
```

But received,

```
--2021-01-24 18:20:43--  https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu
Resolving esm.ubuntu.com (esm.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.46
Connecting to esm.ubuntu.com (esm.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.46|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /infra/ubuntu/ [following]
--2021-01-24 18:20:46--  https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/
Reusing existing connection to esm.ubuntu.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
ubuntu: Permission denied
```

What can i do to fix these GPG keys?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: i'm using 20.10, as i stated in the referenced question. My apologies.

Comment: then remove this package source, supported release at the moment availlable  till focal. this make sense because groovy ist current STS. ESM suport is only for LTS available as far I know.

Comment: ok, will i lose packages from the listed sources? Or are they no longer compatible and/or needed? If i will lose packages or library's, whats the best way to go about removing and replacing?