# Updating Ubuntu to latest 21.04 from 20.04 by command line

Tags: upgrade

There's a problem with upgrading a distro to next one.
Does anyone has an idea what's wrong?

[what I did.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPEdb.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Comment: Your output shows several new-user mistakes: Mis-using dist-upgrade, poor choice of the -y flag, poorly-maintained sources. Trying to jump from 20.04 to 21.04 using dist-upgrade is not tested or supported here -- when (not 'if') something goes wrong, you will be on your own. If you choose to blaze that lonely trail, maintain good backups. You will need them for your inevitable reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is duplicated lines in a file in the sources.list.d folder. According to the warnings the duplicates are in the lines 2 and 3.
See the output below the executed command:
sudo apt-get update

Edit manually that file and remove the duplicated line (if so) and try all commands again.