# I am keep getting warning message when doing "sudo apt-get update". I was trying to do update in kubernetes cluster. How can I resolve it?

Tags: updates, docker, kubernetes

`root@gpus:/home/gpus# apt-get update`

```
Hit:2 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/baseos/ubuntu/focal/x86_64 focal InRelease                                                                
Get:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease [9,383 B]                                                                
Hit:4 https://baltocdn.com/helm/stable/debian all InRelease                                                                 
Ign:5 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:6 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Fetched 237 kB in 3s (87.3 kB/s)                                    
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:1
```

[image: photo of text]
I attached the screenshot of command: cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Please remove the duplicate from your sources.list

Comment: The errors are telling you that your sources are messed up.  It appears that you have duplicates.  Audit the files `/etc/apt/sources.list` as well as any other `.list` files under the directory `/etc/apt` (including subdirectories)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I added my /etc/apt/sources.list file in the question post. But I am unable to decide which one to remove.

Comment: Please do not submit pictures of text, especially without any identification of where it came from. Instead, copy/paste into the body of your question and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).  Please be sure to identify where the text comes from: if it is a file, give us the whole path; if it is the output of a command, provide the command.  It's best if you provide complete information and not bits and pieces.

Comment: Run `sudo sed -i '/kubernetes/d' /etc/apt/sources.list` and see if its working then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Comment: Yes karel, but I don't get it how it resolve my issue. A little explanation will be of great help. Thanks again for the help.