# How do I uninstall bitdefender?

Tags: command-line, gnupg

I followed [this tutorial](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-bitdefender-ubuntu-13-04-official-repository/) to install Bitdefender and now I can't update or upgrade because I'm getting a whole bunch of different erorrs. Screenshot deleted.

I still am getting some errors in my terminal when I try sudo apt update, I followed the tutorial that the previous answer had and it cleared alot of the messages. Screenshot deleted.

Sorry Soren A, I did not know I was not allowed to use screenshots. It won't happen again :)

Here is the output using the grep -nr bitdefender /etc/apt/sources* command : /etc/apt/sources.list.save:58:deb http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb/ bitdefender non-free

Comment: Please don't add terminal text as screenshot, copy/paste the text into the question and format it correctly.

Comment: With the error still persistent, you did more and other things than what is in the tutorial to install bitdefender. Run `grep -nr bitdefender /etc/apt/sources*` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 8):

Following an 8 year old tutorial installing some superfluent (if not harmful) piece of software is not a very good idea I guess ;-)

Fix by deleting the file created in the tutorial:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bitdefender.list
```

Then you should be able to `sudo apt update` again.

Note, that some of your warnings are unrelated to that tutorial and won't go away but also won't be a problem (just warnings). [Check here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times) how to fix this.