# Issue installing ROS noetic on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ros

I've been attempting to install ROS noetic on a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.

I started with setting up the sources list, then setting up the keys, and running `sudo apt update`, following this guide: http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu

However, we did miss the initial step of allowing restricted, universe and multiverse repos.

Afer, we ran `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full` unsuccessfully, and received the following output:

```
luca@luca-Z370P-D3:~$ sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
[sudo] password for luca: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gazebo11 : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libboost-iostreams1.71.0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libboost-program-options1.71.0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libboost-regex1.71.0-icu66 but it is not installable
            Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libgazebo11 (= 11.10.2-1~focal) but 11.10.2+dfsg-1 is to be installed
            Depends: libignition-msgs5 (>= 5.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libignition-transport8 (>= 8.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installable
            Depends: gazebo11-common (>= 11.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: gazebo11-plugin-base but it is not going to be installed
 libgazebo11-dev : Depends: libignition-transport8-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libignition-msgs5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libignition-fuel-tools4-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libignition-common3-profiler-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libdart6-collision-bullet-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not installable or
                            libdart-collision-bullet-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libdart6-collision-ode-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not installable or
                            libdart-collision-ode-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libdart6-utils-urdf-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not installable or
                            libdart-utils-urdf-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libdart6-external-odelcpsolver-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not installable or
                            libdart-external-odelcpsolver-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libdart6-external-ikfast-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not installable or
                            libdart-external-ikfast-dev (< 6.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgazebo11 (= 11.10.2-1~focal) but 11.10.2+dfsg-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: gazebo11-common (>= 11.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: gazebo11-plugin-base (= 11.10.2-1~focal) but it is not going to be installed
 ros-noetic-actionlib : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-actionlib-tutorials : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-bondcpp : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-camera-calibration-parsers : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                                         Depends: libboost-python1.71.0 but it is not installable
                                         Depends: libboost-python1.71.0-py38 but it is not installable
                                         Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
                                         Depends: libyaml-cpp0.6 (>= 0.6.2) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-class-loader : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                           Depends: libpocofoundation62 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-compressed-depth-image-transport : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                               Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                                               Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-compressed-image-transport : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                         Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                                         Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                                         Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-controller-manager : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-cpp-common : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-cv-bridge : Depends: libboost-python1.71.0 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libboost-python1.71.0-py38 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libboost-regex1.71.0-icu66 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-depth-image-proc : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                               Depends: libopencv-calib3d4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                               Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                               Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-diagnostic-aggregator : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                                    Depends: libboost-regex1.71.0-icu66 but it is not installable
                                    Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                    Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-diagnostic-common-diagnostics : Depends: hddtemp but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-diff-drive-controller : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                    Depends: liburdfdom-model but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-eigen-conversions : Depends: liborocos-kdl1.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-filters : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-gazebo-plugins : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                             Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-gazebo-ros : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-gazebo-ros-control : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                                 Depends: ros-noetic-transmission-interface but it is not going to be installed
 ros-noetic-image-geometry : Depends: libopencv-calib3d4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-image-proc : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-image-publisher : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-videoio4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-image-rotate : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                           Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                           Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-image-transport : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-image-view : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-highgui4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-videoio4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-interactive-markers : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-joint-state-controller : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-kdl-conversions : Depends: liborocos-kdl1.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-kdl-parser : Depends: liborocos-kdl1.4 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                         Depends: liburdfdom-model but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-laser-assembler : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-laser-filters : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-nodelet : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-nodelet-tutorial-math : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-pcl-ros : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libpcl-common1.10 (>= 1.10.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libpcl-features1.10 (>= 1.10.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libpcl-filters1.10 (>= 1.10.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libpcl-io1.10 (>= 1.10.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libpcl-search1.10 (>= 1.10.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libpcl-segmentation1.10 (>= 1.10.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libpcl-surface1.10 (>= 1.10.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-pluginlib-tutorials : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-position-controllers : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-robot-state-publisher : Depends: liborocos-kdl1.4 but it is not installable
                                    Depends: liburdfdom-world but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-rosbag : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libboost-program-options1.71.0 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libboost-regex1.71.0-icu66 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                     Depends: ros-noetic-rosbag-storage but it is not going to be installed
 ros-noetic-rosconsole : Depends: libboost-regex1.71.0-icu66 but it is not installable
                         Depends: liblog4cxx10v5 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-rosconsole-bridge : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-roscpp : Depends: libboost-chrono1.71.0 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-roscpp-tutorials : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-rospack : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-program-options1.71.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-rqt-image-view : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                             Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                             Depends: ros-noetic-rqt-gui-cpp but it is not going to be installed
 ros-noetic-rqt-rviz : Depends: libboost-program-options1.71.0 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                       Depends: ros-noetic-rqt-gui-cpp but it is not going to be installed
 ros-noetic-rviz : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libboost-program-options1.71.0 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: liburdfdom-world but it is not installable
                   Depends: libyaml-cpp0.6 (>= 0.6.2) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-rviz-plugin-tutorials : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                                    Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-stage-ros : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-stereo-image-proc : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libopencv-calib3d4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                                Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                                Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-tf : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-tf-conversions : Depends: liborocos-kdl1.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-tf2 : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-tf2-ros : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: ros-noetic-tf2-py but it is not going to be installed
 ros-noetic-theora-image-transport : Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                                     Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                                     Depends: libopencv-imgproc4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-turtle-actionlib : Depends: libboost-thread1.71.0 but it is not installable
 ros-noetic-urdf : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libconsole-bridge0.4 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libtinyxml2-6a (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: liburdfdom-model but it is not installable
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-focal.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.list:1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After recieving this error, we allowed universe, multiverse and restricted repos, ran `sudo apt update` and still had the same results. We're not sure of anymore potential fixes,

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Enable the repositories (at Software & Updates) and try again.

Comment: We reinstalled ubuntu, but we could not find the option at software and updates, and used add-apt-repositories to include universe, multiverse and restricted, how ever we still have an error saying "E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file." when we run sudo apt update

Comment: The repo you're adding doesn't have content for Ubuntu 22.04. ROS.org has those instructions probably thinking about 20.04.

Comment: Ah, I believe I have found the issue - we were using the wrong version of ubuntu, we should of installed 20.04 but instead we installed 22.04. Thanks again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/760896/)