# Failed update from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, raspberrypi

I've been trying to update my Raspberry Pi's Ubuntu version from 20.04 to 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish).
First, I encountered an error where my Software Updater claimed it could not connect to the web, despite that my internet connection was fine. I switched from Main Server to the US Server, and this seemed to solve the problem.

Then, part of the way into the update (during the "Setting New Software Channels" phase), it stopped working and I got a lengthy error message:

`W:Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:43, W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:43, W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:43,...` (I've cut out the middle section, which is mostly more of the same, to save space) `...W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:37 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:37 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50, E:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

The error message is far longer than just this (which is the very start and the very end), and while it all looks mostly like this, I might've missed something important. I can provide the entire error message if that's needed.

Either way, can someone tell me how I can get past this and update Ubuntu to 22.04?

Comment: You STILL have multiple problems. For one, release-upgrades from 20.04 to 22.04 are not turned on yet. See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-1-delayed-until-august-11/29859. Second, read your error messages: Your sources are very much broken and need to be manually fixed.

Comment: @user535733 Could you give me some tips on how to do that? I'm quite new to Ubuntu and don't really know what sources are or how to fix them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times) If you "*don't really know what sources are or how to fix them*," then your output is both curious...and suspicious. It suggests that you tried to "upgrade" to 22.04 in some weird, unsupported way by blindly entering shell incantations that you might not have understood. Can be hard to fix unless we know *exactly* what you did. A link to the instructions would help.

Comment: @user535733 I did attempt a few things with the sources, but it hasn't done anything. No changes to the error message at all, I don't think. This message was appearing before I even did anything severe to the computer anyway, so I'm stumped.
For now, I'll just try wiping the SD and installing 22.04 fresh. I don't have anything useful I'll be losing anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: after upgrade to linux mint 21 cinamon, version 5.4.10, kernal 5.15.0-46-generic,  , I get this same "E:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy- etc..." error.