# Unable to update due to the error: "... is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list"

Tags: upgrade, python3

I want to upgrade but I don't know programming.

When I launch Software Updater, it says "failed to download repository information. check your internet connection." So I click  then it tells me "the software on this computer is up to date. However Ubuntu 22.04 is available (you have 20.04)." When I click  nothing happens. I tried an online guide to update via terminal but that didn't work either.

I'm stuck. I wouldn't mind staying on the current release but I still want to get rid of the errors when trying to update.

`sudo apt update && apt upgrade`:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease              
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]   
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Reading package lists... Done                            
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
```

Someone on reddit suggested I try installing this program then running `aptsources-cleanup`, but I'm having trouble getting past the part where I make the PYZ file executable.

```
peter@scioneaux:~$ sudo apt install python3-apt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-apt is already the newest version (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I might be doing this next step incorrectly. I can see the `aptsources-cleanup.pyz` file in my Downloads folder. So I run this in Terminal, but get an error:

```
peter@scioneaux:~$ chmod a+x aptsources-cleanup.pyz
chmod: cannot access 'aptsources-cleanup.pyz': No such file or directory
```

So I right clicked the PYZ file > properties > permissions > and gave everyone read/write permissions and checked the box to allow executing the file as a program. But it still opens as a text file if I double click

Finally, I tried to run the program from Terminal after changing permissions in the GUI:

```
peter@scioneaux:~$ sudo ./aptsources-cleanup.pyz
sudo: ./aptsources-cleanup.pyz: command not found
```

Obviously I have very limited idea what I'm doing. I'm not computer savvy and never will be. Any help fixing the errors and ultimately upgrading would be appreciated.

Comment: Does these answer your question? See: https://askubuntu.com/q/866901 and https://askubuntu.com/q/760896 and https://askubuntu.com/q/35629

Comment: The system is telling you exactly what is wrong (at least one of the things that is wrong). You have duplicate lines saying the same thing in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I can see what it’s saying. The problem is I don’t understand what the errors mean, let alone how to fix it.

Comment: Remove the duplicate lines from /etc/apt/sources.list