# Updating Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 error

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, package-management, upgrade

I have this error message when trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.

```
W:El objetivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
W:El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:4 y /etc/apt/sources.list:53, 
E:Fallo al obtener http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], 
E:Fallo al obtener http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Fallo al obtener http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], 
E:No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.
```

Comment: Please format your post so that it is readable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) and [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/760896/)

Comment: Title is incorrect - you are trying to update from 18.x to 20.x, and not in reverse

Answer (score -1):

I translated the unfamiliar language into something a normal human can understand and found out that it indicates that there are duplicate entries in your /etc/apt/sources.list file. This can happen when you have added multiple repositories or PPAs to the file.

run

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

and then look for duped entries. Remove the duplicates, and then save using ctrl + o.
Then update apt using `sudo apt-get update`

Also, you should check the package architecture that you are trying to update. In this case it is arm64 and the packages are not available. Arm is basically the type of processor your compute thing uses. (Imma assume you got an apple computer, because of the way you phrased your question)

and you ain't got the ARM version of your `etc/apt/sources.list` file.

You can check the available package for arm64 architecture in the official website of Ubuntu or other trustworthy sources.