# Update crashed wine at all

Tags: apt, wine

Long story short - I'm trying to uninstall broken wine after failed update. I've some problems with broken packages - it gives something like "out of incoming" - I use spanish distribution of OS. So for that reason I'm unable to run wine correctly. After aparenting correct instalation wine doesn't run, because wine32 I'm not able to install.

What I need is delete everything related with wine and try installing from zero. All related stuff seen at a lot of sites was useless.

I've ubuntu 20.04

It gives this:

```
unlock@Acer-Aspire-ES1-331:~$ sudo apt-get install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is a few longer output from apt-update:

```
unlock@Acer-Aspire-ES1-331:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for unlock: 
Hit:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/wine-testing/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit:6 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done            
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
22 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) and [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/760896/)