# Duplicates in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, software-sources, duplicate

**The solution on post:**
[How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)
**dont seem to answer my question since my duplicates are not both inside "/etc/apt/sources.list"

The python script only applies to "/etc/apt/sources.list" and not "/etc/apt/sources.list.d"

System settings >> Software and Updates >> Other Software:

No duplicate there either**

**First of all, sorry my system is installed in french so it might be harder to follow.

(I figure if someone has the skill to help me on this one, he/she will understand the issue anyway trough the outputs I get from terminal. I can translate if needed)**

**Ok so I have most likely installed wine twice, once official way and once more following a tutorial to play starcraft :P (It was fun while it lasted)
Used one or both of those sites:**
http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2021/04/install-starcraft-broodwar-on-ubuntu.html
**and**
https://github.com/edemirkan/wine-starcraft-installer

**Lately when I use "sudo apt update", it works fine but I get this:**

Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Tous les paquets sont à jour.
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr_CA) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr_CA) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1
W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list:55 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources:1

**I tried moving "winehq-focal.sources" out of "/etc/apt/sources.list.d" folder.
But then instead of those errors, I get this instead:**

Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Tous les paquets sont à jour.
W: Une erreur s'est produite lors du contrôle de la signature. Le dépôt n'est pas mis à jour et les fichiers d'index précédents seront utilisés. Erreur de GPG : https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease : Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
W: Impossible de récupérer https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
W: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.

**I found out I could get rid of this by removing the key but I dont seem to have it:**

apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg

pub   rsa2048 2016-06-22 [SC]
D404 0146 BE39 7250 9FD5  7FC7 1F30 45A5 DF75 87C3
uid          [ inconnue] Skype Linux Client Repository se-um@microsoft.com
sub   rsa2048 2016-06-22 [E]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
uid          [ inconnue] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) ftpmaster@ubuntu.com

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid          [ inconnue] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) cdimage@ubuntu.com

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid          [ inconnue] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) ftpmaster@ubuntu.com

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ztefn_ubuntu_haguichi-stable.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2015-07-09 [SC]
D071 2F35 B203 37C0 0C94  E829 EB75 B0EB E2C8 21AC
uid          [ inconnue] Launchpad PPA for Stephen Brandt

**I might add "cat -n  sources.list"**

(Skipping 1 trough 54)
55  deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
56  # deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main

**And "cat -n  winehq-focal.sources"**

1   Types: deb
2   URIs: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu
3   Suites: focal
4   Components: main
5   Architectures: amd64 i386
6   Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key

**Any Idea how to fix this mess? Thank you in advance, it is much appreciated!!!!**

Comment: Please restore the default repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I used: "sudo nano sources.list" and removed line 55 and 56 instead. It worked!!