# I want to smartly this clean up my Ubuntu laptop, but I cannot get snap, gnome working

Tags: apt, gnome, updates, software-center, snap

I recently got a work laptop with Ubuntu  22.04 installed, and I don't want to lose all the software and data because it's all I need for work. I am unable to get the Snap store or GNOME store to load the installed apps so I can get cleaning! I cannot also see the total drive volumes like I can inside Windows.

I'll list down all of the errors I am facing. I get the update pop-up as usual.

[image: Update popup]

I click on update and all is well and good for a while

All is well and good

[image: All well and good]

until I see this error

[image: Update error]

and sometimes when I am doing the update manually I get this error.

[image: Another update error]

So when I try to change some things inside Software and Updates just to debug the issue, I get this popup to update the cache.

[image: Notification to update cache]

I do so to see this kind of window.

[image: Refreshing cache]

After a while it gives me this error, and it is really overwhelming!

[image: Large list of errors]

I am attaching a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14BKc3biPw3Y2Wwnt_66qLle3RapJZu4G?usp=sharing) with more reference material and text files.

I need to clean my system of unwanted apps and files but I am unable to search for them clearly. Also the App menu cannot display all installed apps, because something like Control Panel would've been helpful. I don't want to do a factory reset, but I really want to have a standard way to locate all my files and apps.

Comment: A "work" laptop may be encumbered with a Company Policy that makes what you're doing a firing offfense. Check with your company.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. AskUbuntu uses a question/answer format. It's not a threaded forum. Please ask a single, answerable question. Start with your "Large list of errors." Try the search box at the top of the page: Every one of those errors has been asked and answered before, and are quite easy to learn how to fix.

Comment: Here is the answer for the most common error on your list: [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Comment: As was said, this is multiple errors and not just a single one. When you encounter issues like this it's generally best to handle one at a time from the top down. Also, if you didn't cause the "configured multiple times" issue it may be good to mention that to IT as it's going to cause more trouble inevitably.