# Upgrade of Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 doesn't work

Tags: upgrade

SOLVED

upgrading Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 is having some problems on my machine. Could anyone be so kind and help me please? I tried to upgrade with both graphical interface and in terminal. In terminal it was as follows:

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:22.10.4).
update-manager-core set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
w@inspiron35:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
w@inspiron35:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsecret-tools python-babel-localedata python3-babel python3-dialog
  python3-gnupg python3-jinja2 python3-psutil
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
#
# Canonical released microcode updates for both Intel (CVE-2022-40982) and AMD
# (CVE-2023-20593). ‘Unattended upgrades’ provide security updates by default.
# Ensure it remains enabled to always get all updates as they become available.
#
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  protonvpn protonvpn-cli protonvpn-gui python3-proton-client
  python3-protonvpn-nm-lib
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-typing-extensions
The following packages have been kept back:
  megasync
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 5 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 42.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,306 kB disk space will be freed.
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 python3-typing-extensions all 4.3.0-2
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 python3-typing-extensions all 4.3.0-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-typing-extensions/python3-typing-extensions_4.3.0-2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
w@inspiron35:~$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.10"
VERSION="22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)"
VERSION_CODENAME=kinetic
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=kinetic
LOGO=ubuntu-logo```


AFTER quiverc kind ADVICE (something changed but still not working)

w@inspiron35:~$ sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
[sudo] password for w: 
w@inspiron35:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Get:1 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease [11.9 kB]
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:3 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                  
Get:4 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [6,777 B]    
Hit:5 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                       
Get:6 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2,961 B]          
Get:7 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages [6,267 B]    

> Blockquote

… up to Get:102 

> Blockquote

      
Fetched 51.6 MB in 51s (1,003 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                          
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2

ALL THE SAME "CONFIGURED MULTIPLE TIMES" WARNINGS, ABOUT 100 ITEMS

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsecret-tools python-babel-localedata python3-babel python3-dialog python3-gnupg python3-jinja2 python3-psutil
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  protonvpn protonvpn-cli protonvpn-gui python3-proton-client python3-protonvpn-nm-lib
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-typing-extensions
The following packages have been kept back:
  megasync
The following packages will be upgraded:
  teamviewer
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 5 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 91.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 7,695 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
... ALL SMOOTH
w@inspiron35:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                   
Hit:3 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                   
Hit:4 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                  
Get:5 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2,961 B]
Hit:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Fetched 2,961 B in 1s (2,342 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2

THE CONFIGURED MULTIPLE TIMES WARNINGS ABOUT 100 ITEMS AGAIN

w@inspiron35:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is already the newest version (1:22.10.8).
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core set to manually installed.

w@inspiron35:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

w@inspiron35:~$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core update-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:22.10.4).
update-manager is already the newest version (1:22.10.4).
update-manager set to manually installed.

w@inspiron35:~$ sudo perl -pi -e 's/^Prompt=.*/Prompt=normal/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

w@inspiron35:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-virtual linux-headers-virtual
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsecret-tools python-babel-localedata python3-babel python3-dialog python3-gnupg python3-jinja2 python3-psutil
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,052 B of archives.
After this operation, 43.0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-virtual amd64 5.19.0.46.42 [1,628 B]
Get:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-virtual amd64 5.19.0.46.42 [2,424 B]
Fetched 4,052 B in 1s (6,716 B/s)               
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-virtual.
(Reading database ... 308143 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-virtual_5.19.0.46.42_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-virtual (5.19.0.46.42) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-virtual.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-virtual_5.19.0.46.42_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-virtual (5.19.0.46.42) ...
Setting up linux-headers-virtual (5.19.0.46.42) ...
Setting up linux-image-virtual (5.19.0.46.42) ...
w@inspiron35:~$ sudo apt-get update

SAME AS BEFORE

w@inspiron35:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsecret-tools python-babel-localedata python3-babel python3-dialog python3-gnupg python3-jinja2 python3-psutil
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  megasync
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
w@inspiron35:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
w@inspiron35:~$ do-release-upgrade -m desktop
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.



The upgrade still not working through gui either. Thanks for any new ideas.

I purge removed megasync and the ubuntu upgrade started like a charm now, thank you so much @user535733 and quiverc.
````

Comment: The command `apt dist-upgrade` will **not** upgrade your *kinetic* or 22.10 system to *lunar* or 23.04; the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LunarUpgrades tells you how to perform that upgrade; but you've made it more complex as *kinetic* is EOL & the main archive is moved, and mirrors are free to *drop* support after EOL (*your pasted details show you using a mirror*). Thus you must *enact* procedures covered https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades first

Comment: Thank you very much quiverc for the help, I tried to follow the steps from both links you sent and it seems something is slowly moving forward, the upgrade still not working yet though. I continued as updated in the code above. Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Fixing your self-inflicted "configured multiple times" problem is https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/

Comment: It's right there in your output: `The following packages have been kept back:  megasync`. Fix that or remove it. It's blocking the release-upgrade.

Comment: I purge removed megasync and the ubuntu upgrade started like a charm now, thank you so much @user535733 and quiverc.